# Make middle column take all the remaining space

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've made a usercontrol where my rootcontainer is a grid.

The grid has 3 columns, and I want to make the first and last column a fixed size of 30.
The middle column should take all the remaining space.

But my code is not working..

Here is my code:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="UserControlSolution.UserControlButton"
x:Name="UserControl"
Height="50" Background="{DynamicResource DarkGrey}">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}" StateName="Expand"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
        <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}" StateName="Collapse"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=UserStatusLabel}">
        <ei:GoToStateAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UserControl}" StateName="CenterUserName"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3" To="Expand"/>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="Collapse"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expand">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment)" Storyboard.TargetName="UserCallAlarmPanel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static VerticalAlignment.Top}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Collapse"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <StackPanel x:Name="UserCallAlarmPanel" Grid.Column="0" Background="{DynamicResource DarkGrey}" Margin="0,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Viewbox Height="25"> 
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource calls_icon}" />
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox Height="25"> 
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource alarm_icon}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="UserContainer" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Background="{DynamicResource Red}" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="NameLabel" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FFE5E5E5" Text="Onthaal Telefoon" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="UserStatusLabel" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFE5E5E5"><Run Language="nl-nl" Text="Demeestere advocaten"/></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <Viewbox x:Name="StatusIconContainer" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" OpacityMask="Black"> 
        <ContentControl x:Name="StatusIcon" Content="{DynamicResource appbar_check_orange}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've set the width of the middle column to '*' but that doesn't work apparently.

This is what it looks like when I set the middle column background to blue:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you have to give some width that should be greater than 60 (30+30) or you have to set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in order to take grid the full space. After grid stretches to fill its parent the middle column will take the rest of the space left after 30 and 30 of first and last column

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had to set the HorizontalAlignment of the main grid to Stretch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't define a width for your middle ColumnDefinition and it will fill up all the available space.

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: The asterisk the OP used is the default value, so your code is equivalent to what he already has.